# C: malloc'ed pointer changes location after being returned from function?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that creates and returns a `double*`, but the location seems to change after I return it from the function, which leads to a seg fault.

```
void get_data_internal(double* data, int64_t* i, Factor* fctr) {
    if (fctr->factor_type == DATA_PT) {
        data[*i] = get_factor_data_pt(fctr);
        (*i)++;
    }
    else {
        stSetIterator* child_iter = stSet_getIterator(get_factor_children(fctr));
        Factor* child_fctr = stSet_getNext(child_iter);
        while (child_fctr != NULL) {
            get_data_internal(data, i, child_fctr);
            child_fctr = stSet_getNext(child_iter);
        }
    }
}

double* get_data(HierarchicalDirichletProcess* hdp) {
    int64_t data_length = hdp->data_length;
    double* data = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * data_length);

    int64_t i = 0;
    stSetIterator* base_fctr_iter = stSet_getIterator(hdp->base_dp->factors);
    Factor* base_fctr = stSet_getNext(base_fctr_iter);
    while (base_fctr != NULL) {
        get_data_internal(data, &i, base_fctr);
        base_fctr = stSet_getNext(base_fctr_iter);
    }

    printf("returning data at address %p\n", data);
    return data;
}
```

This gets called from

```
double* data = get_data(hdp);
printf("receiving data at address %p\n", data);
```

Which prints

```
returning data at address 0x10c343000
receiving data at address 0xc343000
```

In every case, the address inside the function is 0x100000000 greater than the address outside the function. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks a lot like you have a conversion to a narrower type somewhere in there (like a cast to `unsigned`).

Comment: There must be something going on that you don't show us. There is no way any of us can replicate this problem without more information.

Comment: What EOF said.  If you want a more confident analysis then do present a [mcve].

Comment: Is `get_data` a function in a DLL or other dynamic library? Is that library build using 64 bits? Is your application that uses the library a 32 bit application? That's the only reason I can see something like that happen, a 64-/32-bit mismatch.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What kind of linker would accept that insanity?

Comment: Perhaps there is no prototype visible at the call `double* data = get_data(hdp);`.  Check to see if your compiler gave a warning for error for that line.

Comment: @M.M That was it! Figures it was something simple like that. Thanks!

Comment: That's why you compile with most warnings possible and with `-werror`

Comment: "X changes after return from function" -> almost always missing prototype and ignored warnings -> we'd need a template for that. (to close them as dupes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is no prototype in scope at the point of the call:

```
double* data = get_data(hdp);
```

In this case the compiler would assume the function returns `int` and so generate the wrong code for handling the return value.

If so, there should be at least two error or warning messages generated - check your compiler output.